# Search Console for Apps - Does the Association of your app with a website help in any way with app store optimization?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, android

I have added my Android app property to my Google Search Console account and now I can use Search Analytics report to see the keyphrases that drive organic traffic to my app on play store. My app is a mobile version of my site (which has a significant organic traffic & PageRank) and the same name with it. However, when someone searches with my site's name from his mobile, I was expecting my app would at least rank on the first page of results after my site, which doesn't happen.

There is an option to [Associate your app with your website](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6212023?hl=en&ref_topic=7000484) so *Google can automatically try to index and crawl your app by inferring the app structure from the website structure, and the website can get a ranking boost in Google Search results*.

Let's say that I don't want my app's pages (I don't use deep linking) to be crawled & indexed instead of my Website pages: Is there any other benefit for the App with the association with my website, if the website has a significant organic performance & authority? Will, in other words, Google favour my app in Google Searches (e.g General Ranking, [App Packs](https://searchengineland.com/figz/wp-content/seloads/2016/02/Picture2.png) etc)?